# Filter data by multiple text boxes in php

Tags: php, html

I have five textboxes which are associated with its own field from the my sql database.What I want to do is fetch data from the mysql database depending on what the user has entered in the text box.Below is my HTML coding.

```
<html>
    <form method="POST" action="t14.php">                        
        Device IP<input type="text" name="D_ip"  size="7%"/><br/>
        Device Name<input type="text" name="name" size="22%" /><br/>
        Interface<input type="text" name="state" size="22%"/> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter"/>                 
    </form>
</html>
```

I want to retrieve data by matching all filed text in the text boxes. If any text box is empty it should skip. I tried with following php coding. But it is not working.Any one know what is the reason.

```
    <html>

    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "901230358v";
        $dbname = "my";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $name = (!empty($_POST['D_ip']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['D_ip']) : false);
            $total_marks = (!empty($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) : false);
            $rank = (!empty($_POST['state']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']) : false);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'details' WHERE 1=1";

            if($name){
                $sql.=" AND 'IP' = ".$name;
            }

            if($total_marks){
                $sql.=" AND 'Name' = ".$total_marks;
            }

            if($rank){
                $sql.=" AND 'State' = ".$rank;
            }

            $result = $conn->query($sql); 

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "ip: " . $row["IP"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " -State: " . $row["State"]. "<br>";
                }
            } 
            else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            $conn->close();
    } 
    ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your logic is correct, the problem is with quotes. Don't put quotes around the column name, and add quotes around the string values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it is still not working. It all ways show           "0 results"

Comment: You mean the code in my answer below, or your attempt to fix it yourself based on the comment?

Answer (score 0):

You have quoting problems. Table and column names shouldn't be quoted (you can put them in backticks if you want, or if you need to because they contain special characters or reserved words). String values must be quoted.

You're also mixing APIs -- if you're using `mysqli`, you must use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, not `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = (!empty($_POST['D_ip']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['D_ip']) : false);
    $total_marks = (!empty($_POST['name']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']) : false);
    $rank = (!empty($_POST['state']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['state']) : false);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE 1=1";

    if($name){
        $sql.=" AND IP = '".$name."'";
    }

    if($total_marks){
        $sql.=" AND Name = '".$total_marks."'";
    }

    if($rank){
        $sql.=" AND `State` = '".$rank."'";
    }

    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "ip: " . $row["IP"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " -State: " . $row["State"]. "<br>";
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: I tried with your code. But it is give this error message Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: There's no `mysql_` at the beginning of the method name. It's just `real_escape_string`.

Comment: When I remove "mysql_" it show following error message with "0 results".

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That means you're getting an error in the query. Add the `or die` that I just added to my answer so you see the SQL error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''details' WHERE 1=1 AND State = 'up'' at line 1

Comment: You had quotes around the table name.